# How to resolve the error "Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1" while initiating Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Download Jmeter and execute the batch file (Jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.6\bin\jmeter.bat).
We get the error message in the console:

```
Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1
```

Kindly help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: What version of Windows, Java (and is it JDK or JRE) and are you running the .bat from the command line, the run menu or a command prompt? If you are using XP or new, are you able to use JMeter by calling it using one of the .cmd files (such as Jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.6\bin\jmeterw.cmd)?

Comment: I had the same problem. I download the 3.0 .zip file from https://github.com/apache/jmeter/releases but didn't realize that was only the source code. Downloading from http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi did it for me.

Comment: If you download the source file from the official website, it's broken as the package is missing the ApacheJMeter.jar (may be it's the corrupted package from the mirror). Go to Archives "http://apache.mirrors.nublue.co.uk//jmeter/binaries/" and get the latest binary (for me it's meter-4.0). That should have the latest ApacheJMeter.jar in the bin folder

Comment: just download the jmeter binaries (tar/zip), NOT 'source' tar/zip.

Answer (score 61):

Try downloading apache-jmeter-2.6.zip from http://www.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/

This contains the proper ApacheJMeter.jar that is needed to initiate.

Go to bin folder in the command prompt and try java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar if the download is correct this should open the GUI.

**Edit on 23/08/2018:**

- **The correct answer as of current modern JMeter versions is** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51973791/460802

Comment: Thank you it works....! Please follow up with this link as it works.. http://www.filewatcher.com/m/apache-jmeter-2.6.zip.23754915-0.html

Comment: By mistake most people gets source of jmeter downloaded instead of binary . Because of that they don't find ApacheJmeter.jar file under bin folder . So download binary not the source

Comment: @sjethvani This should be the answer

Comment: That's the first thing I did

Answer (score 18):

I got this error today because the "[Source](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi#source)" is missing the ApacheJmeter.jar. I downloaded it again from "[Binaries](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi#binaries)" and everything works as expected.

Comment: Worked :) !Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that I downloaded source code instead of binary :)

Comment: How dumb I was :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

JMeter should be started using :

- jmeter/bin/jmeter.sh for Linux
- jmeter/bin/jmeter.bat for windows

this will ensure correct property files are read and necessary jars in lib are loaded.

any other method will expose you to a lot of trouble.

the most upvoted answer is wrong !

See 1.4 Running JMeter in reference documentation :

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

If you'd like to learn more about JMeter and performance testing this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) can help you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running JMeter 2.8 (Windows 7) and received a message similar to that in the original post:

```
C:\>jmeter
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\local\software\jMeter\apache-jmeter-2.8\binApacheJMeter.jar
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'd created a Windows environment variable JMETER_BIN and set it to the JMeter path which I could see contained ApacheJMeter.jar (so it wasn't a question that the jar was missing).

I should have noticed at the time this portion of the error: "binApacheJMeter.jar"

When I went to the jmeter.bat file to troubleshoot, I noticed this line:

```
%JM_START% %JM_LAUNCH% %ARGS% %JVM_ARGS% -jar "%JMETER_BIN%ApacheJMeter.jar" %JMETER_CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

and that caused me to revisit the "binApacheJMeter.jar" portion of the error.

What was happening was that the batch file was requiring a trailing slash on the end of the path in the JMETER_BIN environment variable to correctly specify the location of the .jar.

Once I corrected my environment variable, adding the trailing slash, all was wonderful.

YMMV, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I faced with the same error, when i downloaded the `Jmeter Source`, and it got fixed once i downloaded `Jmeter Binary`. Please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLpEjw_HJe4).

Answer (score 4):

If you'll go through these steps:

1. In the Terminal type `brew install jmeter` and hit Enter
2. When it'll be done type `jmeter` and hit Enter again

You won't have to solve any kind of issue.
Don't thank

Answer (score 1):

navigate to the url http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi-->download  apache-jmeter-2.11.zip, which is under binaries.

this error is occurring since Apache jmeter.jar is missing in bin folder

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux and faced such problem during creating link, try to change jar file path of original jmeter file.

```
+ java -server -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2 -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -jar ./ApacheJMeter.jar -help
```

Change to:

```
java $ARGS $JVM_ARGS -jar "/opt/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use updated [JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) which is `JMeter 3.0` now.

Answer (score 1):

I had moved the apache jmeter folder to c:, open cmd with admin grant and execute jmater.bat.

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error could also happen because of version mismatch of jmeter and java. As jmeter versions supports different java versions as below.

[image: Image of java versions supported for jmeter versions]

Download the zip accordingly and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For people still getting the issue.

I face same problem and seems some .jar file missing.

so try `tar -xf apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz` in the console rather than just right click unzip. And also, try binary package if source package still has an issue.
this solve my issue (I am using ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

For window if you download scr folder say apache-jmeter-5.3_src then you won't find ApacheJMeter.jar file insider bin folder.One might have downloaded zip file under source section. Form this link download zip file under binaries section and click on ApacheJMeter.jar from bin folder https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

Answer (score 0):

When we download the binary of apache-jmeter-x.x.tgz, where x could be any version of apache Jmeter. **ApacheJMeter.jar** must present inside apache-jmeter-x/bin folder , if it is not present somewhere your package not downloaded properly. Cause could be slow internet, or improper shutdown

Download package again and make sure  **ApacheJMeter.jar** present in  apache-jmeter-x/bin folder. Once it is present hit sh jemeter.sh

Answer (score 0):

This issue will come if you download the source from the below URL :
https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi
[image: example : Source apache-jmeter-5.5_src.tgz sha512 pgp apache-jmeter-5.5_src.zip sha512 pgp]

Solution :
Always download :
Apache JMeter 5.5 (Requires Java 8+)
Binaries
apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz   sha512  pgp
apache-jmeter-5.5.zip   sha512  pgp --- > This one
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, You should be downloaded Binaries, Not source from https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

[image]