# Unable to access Jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar Errorlevel=1 with jdk ver 1.8.0.45 in windows 10 64bit

Tags: jmeter

I am using windows 10 64 bit with jdk ver 1.8.0.45.
I have downloaded JMeter 4.0
Now, when I am click on "jmeter.bat" file, I am getting an error message - "Unable to access Jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar Errorlevel=1"

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve the error "Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1" while initiating Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480042/how-to-resolve-the-error-unable-to-access-jarfile-apachejmeter-jar-errorlevel-1)

Answer (score 3):

Download binary zip instead of source zip. That ApacheJMeter.jar error means you are missing the jar at the bin location, you will need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your security is where you work but I have to right-click > Run as Administrator to get jmeter to function properly.  I'm on windows 7.  Try that and see if it helps.